# Перенос цифр из текстового документа в массив

Tags: c#, текст

Добрый день, прошу мне помочь, есть текстовый файл под названием "From" с таким содержанием:

10 1 6 8 6 1 2

Нужно считать все цифры и положить в массив "mas" Чтобы можно было вывести на консоль таким образом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < massiv; i++)
Console.WriteLine("в массиве [{0}] храниться число {1}", i , mas[i]);
```

Чтобы на консоле вывелось:

```
в массиве [0] храниться число 10
в массиве [1] храниться число 1
```

и т.д.

> massiv - это длина массива.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: в чем заключается проблема? [MSDN: Практическое руководство. Чтение из текстового файла (Руководство по программированию на C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx)

Comment: Я не знаю как переносить из текстового документа в массив

Comment: цифры по отдельности

Comment: [MSDN: Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: А что делать если цифры будут рандомные? +  непонятно сколько? @Grundy

Comment: @Grundy  спасибо понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"From.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] text = line.Split(' ');

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("в массиве [{0}] хранится число {1}", i, text[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Все спасибо большое нито я завис никогда с этим не работал

Answer (score 3):

```
// string text = "10 1 6 8 6 1 2";
// для чтения строки из файла 
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\путь_к_файлу\from.txt");
string[] myArray = text.Split();

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("в массиве [{0}] храниться число {1}", i, myArray[i]);
```

Comment: А что делать если цифры будут рандомные? + непонятно сколько? @Ruslan_k

Comment: @ильявитюк: То же самое?

Comment: @Ruslan_K тебе тоже спасибо